# Recaptcha Not Verifying with file_get_contents

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

Confused as to why this isn't working. When the form is submitted I get the error message, meaning my recaptcha verification has failed.

From my form:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="(site-key)"></div>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }

$secretKey = "(secret-key)";
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) === true) {
    echo '<h3>Thanks for your message!</h3>';
} else {
    echo '<h3>Error</h3>';
    }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The reCaptcha documentation **specifically** specifies that the parameters for the request to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify must be sent via POST. You can use CURL for this.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'secret' => $secretKey,
        'response' => $captcha,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($output);

// check response...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I tried to implement this and am getting a blank screen. Should I be checking the response as follows? `if(intval($json["success"]) === true) {
          echo 'success';
        } else {
          echo 'error';
        }`

Comment: @Tom Hey! Check it like this: `if (isset($json->success) && $json->success) { echo 'success'; } else { echo 'error'; }` That should work, however if you do want `$json` to be an associative array add a second argument to `json_decode` with the value true, this will return an associative array instead of an object :)

Comment: My heroooo! Thank you sir.

Comment: @Tom Glad I could help!

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `file_get_contents`. Google suggests using POST requests.
You may use something in the lines of the following

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'secret' => $secretKey,
        'response' => $captcha
    )
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if(strpos($response, '"success": true') !== FALSE) {
    echo '<h3>Thanks for your message!</h3>';
} else {
    echo "<h3>Error</h3>";
}
```

**EDIT**

Yemiez answer (just got me at the corner) is better at handling the response part, by using the `json_decode` function.

**EDIT**
just fixed a typo

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){  
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];  
}  
$recaptcha_secret = '(secret-key)';  
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$captcha);  
$response = json_decode($response, true);  
if(!empty($response["success"]))  
{  
    echo 'Thanks for your message!';  
} else {  
    echo 'Error';  
}
```

Comment: Just code makes for a minimally helpful post. Explain what your code does and why it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `file_get_contents` still currently works to confirm the reCaptcha; while not recommended.
I do believe the problem with your code lies within the code at:

```
if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) === true) {
    echo '<h3>Thanks for your message!</h3>';
} else {
    echo '<h3>Error</h3>';
}
```

Remove the `intval()` as this is unneeded and turns your boolean value into an int.  The `===` also compares the type so the response will always be converted to an int and of course false when compared to the boolean `true`.  Either this or change `true` to `1`.  So it should be:

```
if($responseKeys["success"] === true) {
    echo '<h3>Thanks for your message!</h3>';
} else {
    echo '<h3>Error</h3>';
}
```